# Remove outer array from JSON in Python dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, json, dataframe, api

I am using the following code to create an Excel file from an API JSON:

```
import requests

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("my API url")


df.to_excel("myFileLocation.xlsx")
```

The problem is that my JSON doesn't parse correctly, due to an outer array in the API (I've tested by manually altering the JSON to remove the "outer array" and it parses correctly):

```
{"outer array": [{"Header1": "Value1", "Header2": Value2},{"Header1": "Value3", "Header 2": Value 4}]}
```

How can I update my existing code to remove this outer array?

Comment: It's not clear to me what data you actually want. You want to eliminate everything before the `[`? There doesn't seem to be an inner array.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(d["outer array"])` if `d` is the dictionary you pasted.

Comment: @codebling Yes, if my JSON starts with [{"Header1"... then it parses correctly. So I would need to remove {"outer array": and the closing }

Comment: @not_speshal I don't know what you mean. Where would I insert that piece of code and what is d?

Comment: Does your API return a json (string)? What you posted above is a Python dictionary.

Comment: @not_speshal What I posted above was an example of what my API JSON looks like.

Comment: Then assuming that is `d`, you simply want `df = pd.DataFrame(d["outer array"])` ?

Comment: @not_speshal how could that be `d` -- Pandas actually retrieves the data from the URL. `"my API url"` is an actual URL read by Pandas. The URL returns JSON, which is parsed by Pandas. There is no Python dictionary here.

Comment: Just get the json with `requests` first, then pass the dictionary item `outer array` to pandas.

Comment: @Codebling - OP is clearly not able to get the DataFrame they need with the existing code. They could parse the json to a dictionary (stored in `d`) using `json.loads` or something else and do what I said.

Comment: Codebling - See what @RJAdriaansen said to answer your "how could that be `d`"

Comment: @not_speshal agreed, both of you. This is what OP is asking how to do.

Comment: @Codebling - Yes, and if their question was clearer, we would post a code answer. What OP has pasted above is a `dict`. If it was a json (string), it would need to be enclosed in "".

Comment: What the OP has posted is a JSON string. Perhaps that was not clear to everyone

Comment: I am a newbie and you will have to be more specific. Can you paste the exact code I need?

Comment: @Codebling - "String" would need to be enclosed in quotes as mentioned. So `'{"outer array": []}'` is a json but `{"outer array": []}` is a `dict`

Comment: It is rather pointless to argue about this, so I will stop and just leave it at "I disagree".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the json returned by your URL is as follows:

```
d = '{"outer array": [{"Header1": "Value1", "Header2": "Value2"}, {"Header1": "Value3", "Header2": "Value4"}]}'
```

You could simply parse this `json` before calling `pd.DataFrame`:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

d = requests.get("http://my/api/url/").json()
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(d)["outer array"]) #if d is a string
#df = pd.DataFrame(d["outer array"]) #uncomment if d is not a string

>>> df
  Header1 Header2
0  Value1  Value2
1  Value3  Value4
```

Comment: Instead of "d" am I putting my URL?

Comment: @Bob - No. Save the `json` returned by your URL to `d`. See the edit.

Comment: I got an erro: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict. The JSON that I posted doesn't have " at beginning

Comment: Then just try `df = pd.DataFrame(d["outer array"])`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do some manipulation before passing the data to Pandas, which unfortunately means you'll need to retrieve the data from the URL yourself.

You can do this as a string manipulation, or parse it into a dictionary and access the value. Using string manipulations:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("my API url")
df = pd.read_json(response.text.removeprefix('{"outer array": ').removesuffix('}'))
```

You may need to install Requests:

```
python -m pip install requests
```

Comment: I got error: AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'removeprefix'