How to scrape a csv table contained within a JavaScript button using Python?
I am trying to pull a csv table from a webpage into a pandas dataframe within a Jupyter Notebook, a process I have successfully implemented several times for other websites in the past, but I am running into a challenge with this one.
The table I am trying to pull is only available as a JavaScript response to a button click instead of being available at a specific URL.
Here is the URL: https://ciffc.net/national // The table I am trying to scrape is contained within the Export (CSV)  button in red.
I have tried implementing a solution using pandas.read_csv, but I can't seem to point to the button in question.
Of note, I am using Jupyter Notebooks within the ArcGIS Online environment.
Thank you!

What makes this different your other efforts? "I am trying to pull a csv table from a webpage into a pandas dataframe within a Jupyter Notebook, a process I have successfully implemented several times for other websites in the past, but I am running into a challenge with this one." Share some code examples of that and how you tried adapting those to this? One thing that may be different that I see here is that this is a dynamic page and not a static page and so you don't just get the URL. But because you share no code, I cannot tell if you already know this?

The json for example for page 1 seems to be available over the stable URL https://api.ciffc.net//v1/wildfires?page=1.
So if you don't mind doing some extra formatting on the DataFrame you can use:
import pandas
import requests

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(
    requests.get('https://api.ciffc.net//v1/wildfires?page=1').json()["rows"])

Which contains:




field_agency_fire_id
field_agency_code
field_agency_data_timezone
field_situation_report_date
field_status_date
field_stage_of_control_status
field_system_fire_cause
field_response_type
field_fire_size
field_latitude
field_longitude
full_count




0
SS007-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-12T22:21:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OC
N
MON
1
60.5853
-116.902
1515


1
FS005-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-13T17:40:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
UC
N
FUL
22
61.52
-121.393
1515


2
SS015-24
nt
MDT
2024-06-01T21:57:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OC
N
FUL
0.2
60.0809
-117.185
1515


3
SS008-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-23T23:24:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OC
N
MON
8
60.2382
-118.13
1515


4
SS003-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-05T19:45:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OUT
N
FUL
0.01
60.6161
-116.073
1515


5
FS006-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-13T21:47:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OC
N
MON
2930
61.2465
-119.392
1515


6
ZF004-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-25T17:55:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OUT
H
FUL
0
62.4502
-114.401
1515


7
ZF001-24
nt
MDT
2024-02-05T15:00:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OUT
H
FUL
0.05
62.3217
-114.252
1515


8
SS012-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-25T18:00:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OUT
H
FUL
0.1
61.1722
-113.669
1515


9
SS009-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-24T16:08:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OC
N
MOD
5681
60
-117
1515


10
SS005-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-10T20:10:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OUT
H
FUL
0.5
60.5885
-116.176
1515


11
SS004-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-05T20:45:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
BH
N
FUL
3
60.3924
-117.896
1515


12
SS002-24
nt
MDT
2024-04-23T06:00:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OUT
N
FUL
0.5
60.3258
-112.282
1515


13
SS001-24
nt
MDT
2024-04-23T06:00:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OUT
N
FUL
2
60.119
-112.281
1515


14
ZF007-24
nt
MDT
2024-06-06T22:37:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OUT
H
FUL
0
62.5128
-113.694
1515


15
ZF005-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-26T13:00:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OUT
H
FUL
0
62.5185
-114.319
1515


16
ZF003-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-23T23:30:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OUT
H
FUL
5
63.4575
-116.098
1515


17
ZF002-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-19T23:45:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OUT
H
FUL
0.01
62.4923
-113.521
1515


18
SS014-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-29T23:55:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OUT
N
FUL
2.5
60.2638
-116.334
1515


19
SS013-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-27T20:18:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OUT
N
FUL
0.5
60.3
-116.65
1515


20
SS011-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-24T18:40:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OUT
N
FUL
1
60.9028
-112.421
1515


21
SS010-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-24T18:22:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OC
N
MOD
28
60.9536
-112.39
1515


22
ZF006-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-31T21:49:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OC
N
MON
145
62.5954
-119.058
1515


23
SS006-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-10T21:49:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OUT
N
MON
1
60.6623
-115.978
1515


24
FS004-24
nt
MDT
2024-05-10T18:20:00.000Z
2024-06-14T20:00:10.000Z
OC
N
MOD
11894
61.1473
-119.376
1515




I did this with Selenium using some Javascript resources as you said, the bottom needs to be clicked using JS to download the file.
Like:
def download_file(self):
    try:
        self.setup_driver()
        url = "https://ciffc.net/national"
        self._driver.get(url)
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(self._driver, 20)
        button_download = wait.until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'table-filter')]//button[contains(@class, 'button')]"))
        )
        
        self._driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button_download)
        
        time.sleep(2)
        
        downloaded_file = self.get_downloaded_file_path()
        
        df = pd.read_csv(downloaded_file)
        print(df)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        if self._driver:
            self._driver.quit()
            
def get_downloaded_file_path(self):
    files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
    files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
    return os.path.join(os.getcwd(), files[-1])

This code is simple and will work fine to find the element and execute a click to download the file and convert it into pandas dataframe. The detail here is the self._driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button_download) which is needed for these situations!
Entire code if you need:
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import 
expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import 
ChromeDriverManager
import os
import time

class FileHandlerX:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._chrome_options = self.define_options()
        self._driver = None
    
    def define_options(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        prefs = {
           "download.prompt_for_download": False,
           "download.directory_upgrade": True,
           "safebrowsing.enabled": True,
           "download.default_directory": os.getcwd()
        }
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", 
    prefs)
    return chrome_options

   def setup_driver(self):
    chrome_service = 
 Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    self._driver = 
 webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, 
 options=self._chrome_options)
    self._driver.implicitly_wait(10)

def download_file(self):
    try:
        self.setup_driver()
        url = "https://ciffc.net/national"
        self._driver.get(url)
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(self._driver, 20)
        button_download = wait.until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
 "//div[contains(@class, 'table- 
  filter')]//button[contains(@class, 'button')]"))
        )
        
        
self._driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", 
button_download)
        
        time.sleep(2)
        
        downloaded_file = 
        self.get_downloaded_file_path()
        
        df = pd.read_csv(downloaded_file)
        print(df)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        if self._driver:
            self._driver.quit()
            
    def get_downloaded_file_path(self):
        files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
        files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
        return os.path.join(os.getcwd(), files[-1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = FileHandlerX()
    test.download_file()

Some resources about the details:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-click-button-selenium-python and
https://youtu.be/xhnOGgPrdj0?si=bshEDsk6ukzlRcEl

This works for me, even in JupyterLite with Python(Pyodide) kernel:
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://api.ciffc.net//v1/wildfires?export=true'
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()


# So want to skip `rows': [` part because the other part seems to have the column headers and data:
#solution to bypassing outer level from 
# answer to 'Remove outer array from JSON in Python dataframe' https://stackoverflow.com/a/69800668/8508004

d = requests.get(url).json()
#df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(d)["rows"]) #if d is a string 
df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData["rows"]) #uncomment if d is not a string
df

Details:
These were the two main resources to put that together:

an answer and comments therein to 'Want to click download csv button using Selenium Python, but button changes class-name when hovered over?'
an answer to 'Remove outer array from JSON in Python dataframe'

Let me know if you need any further clarification.
